# Luhn's algorithm works for all credit cards except for AMEX cards (Python3) (cs50/pset6/credit)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cs50, luhn

I'm trying to create a program that checks whether the credit card number the user inputed is either invalid, or from AMEX, MASTERCARD, or VISA. I'm using Luhn's formula. Here is a site that contains the explanation to the formula I'm using: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/luhn-algorithm/

It works with all credit card numbers, except credit cards from AMEX. Could someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
number = input("Number: ")
valid = False
sumOfOdd = 0
sumOfEven = 0

def validation(credit_num):
    global sumOfOdd
    global sumOfEven
    position = 0
    for i in credit_num:
        if position % 2 != 0:
            sumOfOdd += int(i)
        else:
            product_greater = str(int(i) * 2)
            if len(product_greater) > 1:
                sumOfEven += (int(product_greater[0]) + int(product_greater[1]))
            else:
                sumOfEven += int(product_greater)
        position += 1

def main():
    if (sumOfOdd + sumOfEven) % 10 == 0:
        if number[0] == "3":
            print("AMEX")
        elif number[0] == "5":
            print("MASTERCARD")
        else:
            print("VISA")


    else:
        print("INVALID")

    print(f"{sumOfOdd + sumOfEven}")
validation(number)
main()
```

Here are some credit card numbers:
VISA: `4111111111111111`
MASTERCARD: `5555555555554444`
AMEX: `371449635398431`
I've found many different ways to calculate this formula, but I'm not sure if mine is correct.

Comment: You need to count digits from the right, so that the final digit of the card number is NOT one that you double.  Your code gets this wrong for numbers of odd length.

Comment: But @jasonharper the Amex card has the same length as Mastercard's and visa's

Comment: `5105105105105100` has the sum of 20 (valid) and is recognized as MasterCard, because it starts with 5.

Comment: An American Express card number is 15 digits.  A Mastercard number is 16 digits.  A Visa card number may be 13 or 16 digits.  You should heed the advice of jasonharper.

Comment: I'm sorry! I placed the wrong AMEX card number. I'll update my question